# React: Pass Firebase Data Down Via Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pass some Firebase data down from one component via `props` to another component, but it doesn't seem to be letting me iterate over the Firebase data in the child component.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const gamesRef = firebase.database().ref('games').orderByKey();

    gamesRef.once('value', snap => {
      snap.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        this.state.games.push(childSnapshot.val());
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Games data={ this.state.games } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Games.js**

```
class Games extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.data); // this logs successfully  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="Games flex flex-end flex-wrap">
          { this.props.data.map(function (game, i) {            
            return (
              <h1>{ game.title }</h1>
            )
          }) }
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason I'm having a problem when trying to `map()` over my `props.data`. It's definitely being passed down to my `Games` component, because it's printing the `console.log(this.props.data)` to the console with the data it gets back from Firebase.

Do I have to wait for my Firebase data to resolve before mapping over it, and if so how do I do this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies with your componentDidMount in your App class. You're updating state with

```
this.state.games.push(childSnapshot.val());
```

You shouldn't do that. State should only be updated with this.setState (or at the very least you should use this.forceUpdate()), as otherwise it will not re-render. I would instead advise doing

```
componentDidMount() {
  const gamesRef = firebase.database().ref('games').orderByKey();
  let newGames;

  gamesRef.once('value', snap => {
    snap.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      newGames.push(childSnapshot.val());
    })
  })

  this.setState({games: newGames});
}
```

This will cause a re-render of the App component, causing the new data to be passed as a prop to the Games component.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had to end up putting the `this.setState()` line inside the firebase callback. This seemed to work!